# how to get the count and pop a message box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am trying to get the message box to show the elements but messagebox will not pop when I run the application

```
string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<widgets>
    <widget>
        <url>~/Portal/Widgets/ServicesList.ascx</url>
        <castAs>ServicesWidget</castAs>
        <urlType>ascx</urlType>
        <parameters>
            <PortalCategoryId>3</PortalCategoryId>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
    <widget>
        <url>www.omegacoder.com</url>
        <castAs>ServicesWidget</castAs>
        <urlType>htm</urlType>
        <parameters>
            <PortalCategoryId>41</PortalCategoryId>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>";

XDocument loaded = XDocument.Parse( xml );

var widgets = from x in loaded.Descendants( "widget" )
              select new
              {
                  URL = x.Descendants( "url" ).First().Value,
                  Category = x.Descendants( "PortalCategoryId" ).First().Value
              };

MessageBox.Show("one");
foreach ( var wd in widgets ){
MessageBox.Show("two");

 }
```

MessageBox.Show("one"); shows up.
 MessageBox.Show("two"); never pops up

Also what if I wanna see a count of widgets> I am new to C#
thanks

Comment: Did you try and step through with a debugger?

Comment: Do you get an error? Are you using a console app?

Comment: I replaced the MessageBox calls with Console.WriteLine (ran in NUnit) and this code worked as expected (2 "two"s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your LINQ query with:

```
var widgets = from x in loaded.Descendants("widgets").Descendants( "widget" )
          select new
          {
              URL = x.Descendants( "url" ).First().Value,
              Category = x.Descendants( "PortalCategoryId" ).First().Value
          };
```

**UPDATE:**
Both versions of LINQ should work correctly. My mistake, **Descendants** can point not only to directly nested nodes, but to all the nodes in the subtree.

**Probable issue cause:**
However, be aware that in order to show the second message box, you have to close the first one. I've just tested this and it worked.

**Suggested solution:**
In order to be available to show multiple dialogs with messages, you can just create your own form class in the project, instantiate it and show it with **Show()** method i.e.:
you can add a new *Windows Form*, call it **MessageForm** and use the following code:

```
//MessageBox.Show(new Form(), "one");
        MessageForm msgDlg = new MessageForm() { Message = "one" };
        msgDlg.Show(this);
        foreach (var wd in widgets)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(new Form(), "two");
            MessageForm msgDlgS = new MessageForm() { Message = "two" };
            msgDlgS.Show(this);
        }
```

It should work as intended then.

Answer (score 2):

If you try `MessageBox.Show(widgets.Count().ToString())` my bets are it will say `0`. It is defined behaviour of for loop to do NO iterations on a collection with 0 elements. So "two" is never displayed.

#### EDIT -

As to why it would be zero that's obviously a problem if it is! Maybe you need to loop thru `from x in loaded.Descendants( "widgets/widget" )` ???

I don't remember if  XDocument forces you to swallow past the documentelement or not like XMLDocument does.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
MessageBox.Show("one");
```

by

```
MessageBox.Show(widgets.Count()); //.Count(), not .Count
```

Check if you have any elements to loop through!